Troubleshooting e-Paper Connection Issues on Custom PCB Board: Seeking Advice
We are using a 0.97-inch LCD in our project. We customized the design in our PCB using the Despi-Co2 and designed it accordingly. Please see the attached image for the schematic diagram of our PCB.
All other functions of the PCB are working fine except for the E-paper LCD. It is not working and appears to be open. Please take a look and see what the mistake might be



In the attached file, we have debugged the PCB. Please review it to identify where we made mistakes so we can correct them.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WSO8oxxqEdzw-kANF4itV_zR-jIuIbwl/view?usp=sharing

Please add a datasheet of the display.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eo05tH0KfI-ZNQiG_o9sBTtz9p6q4iuZ/view?usp=sharing

The inductor in combination with the FET is used to create auxiliary higer voltages for the display. You cannot simply feed this point with a DC voltage. R1 in the datasheet is 1 Mohm, why did you change it to 10 kohm?

Thanks, @Jens you save a lot of time we change the resistor and it works.

Nice to hear :) Seams to be a very weak driver output or contains a series resistor.
